# How automatically update EMF ResourceSet on file change?

Tags: eclipse-emf

I need to have always up to date content of some file in my program.
I've created an EMF resource set.

Because `resourceSet.getResource(resourceURI, true)` takes a lot of time to complete I store the resource set in a static field, so files can be cached.

I.e. once `resourceSet.getResource(resourceURI, true)` is called for some URI the file is cached in `resourceSet`.

The problem is that `resourceSet` doesn't update it's cache automatically:

I.e.:

```
resourceSet.getResource(resourceURI, true);
// delete resourceURI from file system

// Here I expect null, but old version of the file is returned
resourceSet.getResource(resourceURI, true);
```

How to force `resourceSet` to update cache if needed?

I'm using `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl`, but probably I need another version of `ResourceSet` that takes modification stamps into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: first if you want to reload the resource, you'll have to call

```java
aResource.unload([..]);
aResource.load([..])
```

As EMF is not requiring Eclipse in any way the `Resource` and `ResourceSet` classes are not the same as the Eclipse workspace `IResource` subclasses, which mean changing a file on the file system will not cause the EMF Resources to be reloaded.

It's pretty easy to do though, have a look on the `XxxxEditor` EMF generated for you, the class instantiate a `IResourceChangeListener` which will receive deltas from the Eclipse workspace when a file is being modified. The generated listener process these deltas by reloading the resources.

```java
protected IResourceChangeListener resourceChangeListener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();
        //find out which EMF Resource matches with the IResource and reload it
    }
}
```

Comment: so this means that I have to write my own "smart" implementation of ResourceSet :) it's possible to check if the file has been changed using eclipse "timestamps"

Comment: The Eclipse workspace will do the work for you and notify your listener when there is an actual change. This change might happen when an editor saves or for instance when the workspace gets refreshed in regard to the file system.

Comment: When I try this all my model objects are set to be proxies when I call `unload`. This is normal and described by the documentation. But when I call `load` the model objects keep being proxies and they are not updated with the new information from the file. Do you have any idea about why this is the case and what I can do about it?

Comment: My problem turned out to be that when I call `load` I get *new* objects for all contents in the resource. The old ones are marked as proxies and removed from the resource, and are not re-inserted when the resource is re-loaded. So I had to use the new objects instead of the old ones.